# What is the limit of $\log(a x + b + c) - \log(d x + g + h)$ as $x \rightarrow \infty$?

Tags: calculus, limits, logarithms

I know that as $x$ approaches infinity, $\log(a x + b + c)$ where $a, b, c$ are constants, will also go to infinity. The same argument can be made for $\log(d  x + g + h)$, where $d, g, h$ are constants.

However, what is the limit of $\log(a  x + b + c) - \log(d  x + g + h)$ as $x \rightarrow \infty$? I'm not sure how to deal with a difference in infinities.

Comment: Write the difference as the logarithm of a quotient ...

Comment: You should also clarify if $a$ or $d$ can be negative or zero.

Comment: @MartinR Okay, so write the difference as the log of a quotient, then use l'hopital's rule?

Comment: @Devon No, then find the limit of the quotient and determine the limit of the log from that. (Well, you*can* use l'Hôpital for the first, but I'd consider that too big a gun for this)

Comment: The limit of the quotient is $\infty/\infty$ as $x$ approaches $\infty$ right? So is there another way to find the limit besides the l'Hopital's rule? I'd also like to clarify that $a$ and $d$ are positive.

Comment: Assume $a, d > 0$. Notice $\log(\alpha x + \beta) = \log(x) + \log(\alpha + \frac{\beta}{x})$, the "divergent" part of both $\log(ax + b + c)$ and $\log(dx + g + h)$ is the same "$\log x$". You can cancel it out before taking limit.

Comment: An **informal** alternative way of expressing the idea in the comment of @achillehui is that as $x \to \infty$ the $b,c,g,h$ terms become *relatively* trivial and should therefore be ignored.

Comment: $\frac{ax+b}{cx+d}=\frac{\frac ac(cx+d)+b-\frac{ad}c}{cx+d}=\frac ac+\frac{bc-ad}{c^2x+dc}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can alternatively write the difference of logarithms as:

$ln(\frac{a x+b+c}{d x+g+h})$

And bring everything back to the limit of the logarithm which is equal to the logarithm of the limit.
That is to say the limit of a polynomial fraction with polynomials of the same degree, therefore the limit for x tending to infinity is equal to the ratio of the coefficients of the powers that have the same degree, namely;

$ln(\frac{a}{d})$.